# PHP param type hinted with '?'

Tags: php, code-documentation

I was reading through some of the Zend framework's hydration source code and came across something I haven't encountered before:

```
public function hydrate(string $name, ?array $data = null) : string
```

I've never seen something type hinted like the `$data` parameter - `?array`

I don't know what to search for, so finding documentation on the syntax used there is really difficult. Does anyone know what it is called when you type hint with a question mark like that, and possibly what it does?

Even if you only point me at the right documentation I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

It declares `$data` as nullable, as described in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)